# Sencha touch - Ext.XTemplate if/else not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, template-engine

Hi I am new to Sencha touch. I have problem displaying data in `Ext.dataview.List` with `itemTpl`. This how I am setting `itemTpl` in `config`

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(

            '<div class="featureImageHolder"><img class="featureImage" src="{itemImage}" alt="{itemName}" /></div>',

            '<span class="item">',
                '<h3 class="saleName">{itemName}</h3>',
                '<span class="priceOptions">',
                '<tpl for="prices">',
                    '<span class="priceOptionReg">',
                        '<tpl if="priceOptionDesc">{priceOptionDesc}</tpl> ',
                        '<tpl if="priceOptionReg">{priceOptionReg}</tpl>  ',
                        '<tpl if="priceReg">${priceReg}</tpl>  ',
                        '<tpl if="priceRegSuffix">{priceRegSuffix}</tpl> ',
                    '</span>',
                    '<tpl if="priceSale"><span class="priceOptionSale">',
                        '<tpl if="priceSaleDesc">{priceSaleDesc}</tpl> ',
                        '<tpl if="priceOptionSale">{priceOptionSale}</tpl>  ',
                        '<tpl if="priceSale">${priceSale}</tpl>',
                        '<tpl if="priceSaleSuffix">{priceSaleSuffix}</tpl> ',
                    '</span></tpl>',
                '</tpl>',
                '</span>',
            '</span>',
            '<div class="clear"></div>'
        ),
```

It is working perfectly and displaying list of products. But now I need change CSS class for first record only because it is an Ad banner. So I am using following if statement:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                '<tpl if={isBanner} === true>',
                    '<div class="myTestClass">{itemImage}</div>',

                '<tpl elseif={isBanner} === false>',
                    '<div class="featureImageHolder"><img class="featureImage" src="{itemImage}" alt="{itemName}" /></div>',
                '</tpl>',


                '<span class="item">',
                    '<h3 class="saleName">{itemName}</h3>',
                    '<span class="priceOptions">',
                    '<tpl for="prices">',
                        '<span class="priceOptionReg">',
                            '<tpl if="priceOptionDesc">{priceOptionDesc}</tpl> ',
                            '<tpl if="priceOptionReg">{priceOptionReg}</tpl>  ',
                            '<tpl if="priceReg">${priceReg}</tpl>  ',
                            '<tpl if="priceRegSuffix">{priceRegSuffix}</tpl> ',
                        '</span>',
                        '<tpl if="priceSale"><span class="priceOptionSale">',
                            '<tpl if="priceSaleDesc">{priceSaleDesc}</tpl> ',
                            '<tpl if="priceOptionSale">{priceOptionSale}</tpl>  ',
                            '<tpl if="priceSale">${priceSale}</tpl>',
                            '<tpl if="priceSaleSuffix">{priceSaleSuffix}</tpl> ',
                        '</span></tpl>',
                    '</tpl>',
                    '</span>',
                '</span>',
                '<div class="clear"></div>'
            ),
```

The problem is `if/elseif` are both executed for each record. If I use `if/else` it gives error in console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
```

You can see I have used

`'<tpl if={isBanner} === true>',`

I have also used

```
'<tpl if={isBanner} == true>',
```

I have also tried many varients like comparing numeric values instead of Boolean and using `&gt;` or `&lt;`. Also tried comparing String values. But with all variations, the `if/elseif` are both executing and `if/else` gives error.

Any help is appreciated, I just need to change class for first record.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if isBanner is boolean, this will work

```
'<tpl if="isBanner">',
     '<div class="myTestClass">{itemImage}</div>',
'<tpl else>',
     '<div class="featureImageHolder"><img class="featureImage" src="{itemImage}" alt="{itemName}" /></div>',
'</tpl>',
```

Comment: thanks it worked!. Can you please specify when to use isBanner, and when to use {isBanner}?

Comment: I suppose string "isBanner" can be used inside <tpl> tag, and {isBanner} needs to be used inside other tags (like <p> and <div>)..

Comment: can you check for value, like isBanner = 3 or something like that if isBanner is not boolean?